# Python function error

Tags: python

I have a date field in attribute table looks like this "11/04/2020 14:25:05" and I am trying to run the below function from field calculator

```
def date_info(strDT):
    import datetime
    dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDT, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S')
    weekday = dt_obj.isoweekday()
    return weekday
```

but it returns an error as below
any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to add the messages as text within the question  body. Images are not legible on all platforms, and cannot be searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'` You have 24hour time not 12hour time. From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> %H Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
>
> %I Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.

Comment: Thanks user2856. I tried it but it didn't work. I even tried a different date field with 12 hours date format and still not working

Comment: It *should* work. It returns `6` by me, which is the correct weekday for your input string. If it doesn't, you'd better update your question with the new error message.

Comment: I tried again and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot